# How to set view model on ViewResult in request filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, filter, viewresult

I make a MVC project and I want set Model into View from filter.

But I do not kown ,How can I do this.

the Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Contorller:

```
[CustomFilter(View = "../Test/Test")]//<===/Test/Test.cshtml
public ActionResult Test(TestModel testModel)//<===Model from Page
{
      //the Model has Value!!
       // if has some exception here
        return View(model);//<=====/Test/Test.cshtml
}
```

filter(just demo):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
     ViewResult vr = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult()
     {
            ViewName = this.View,//<======/Test/Test.cshtml
            ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData                             
      };
      //How can I set Model here?!!
      vr.Model = ???? //<========the Model is only get
      filterContext.Result = vr;
}
```

**Edit begin** thanks for @Richard Szalay @Zabavsky @James @spaceman

change filter extends to HandleErrorAttribute

```
  ViewResult vr = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult()
     {
            ViewName = this.View,//<======/Test/Test.cshtml
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(filterContext.Controller.ViewData)
            {
                //I want get testModel from Action's paramater
                //the filter extends HandleErrorAttribute
                Model = new { ID = 3, Name = "test" }// set the model
            }                             
      };
```

**Edit end**

Test/Test.chtml

```
@model TestModel
<h2>Test</h2>
@Model //<=====model is null
```

when I request

```
http://localhost/Test/Test?ID=3&Name=4
```

The Test Page can not get Model.

Answer (score 31):

```
ViewResult vr = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = this.View, //<======/Test/Test.cshtml
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(filterContext.Controller.ViewData)
            {
                Model = // set the model
            }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I Also want to kown ,In filter { Model = testModel<==how to get Action's Model here }

Comment: @zt9788, `OnActionExecuting` runs before the action, you don't have any model yet.

Comment: if filter extends HandleErrorAttribute and the exception throw in Action. Is it can get Model?

Answer (score 9):

from the asp.net mvc source, they just set the model in view data.
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs

```
 protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }

        return new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = viewName,
            MasterName = masterName,
            ViewData = ViewData,
            TempData = TempData,
            ViewEngineCollection = ViewEngineCollection
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the filter context, and set the View, the Model, the ViewData and whatever you want. You have to take some things into account:

```
// You can specify a model, and some extra info, like ViewBag:
ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary
{
    Model = new MyViewModel
    {
        ModelProperty = ...,
        OtherModelProperty = ...,
        ...
    } 
};

// You can take into account if it's a partial or not, to return a View 
// or Partial View (casted to base, to set the remaining data):
ViewResultBase result = filterContext.IsChildAction
    ? new PartialViewResult()
    : (ViewResultBase) (new ViewResult());

// Set the remaining data: Name of the View, (if in Shared folder) or
// Relative path to the view file with extension, like "~/Views/Misc/AView.cshtml"
result.ViewName = View;                     
result.ViewData = viewData;     // as defined above

// Set this as the result
filterContext.Result = result;
```

In this way, your View will receive the model, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The model property is really just a ViewDataDictionary, you can initialise an instance of that with your actual model i.e.

```
vr.Model = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
```

Comment: How do you do that in ControllerBase?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the controller from the filtercontext and use the View method on the controller, like so:

```
filterContext.Result = (filterContext.Controller as Controller).View(model);
```